# Two UICollection View on One View is Not display multiple images

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am opening a view in which i use two collection view to display image one is beforeParcelColextionView Another is AfterParcelCollectionView. This Collection view can able to display one image but it will not display multiple images.After loading multiple images the images are not shown in my frames of collection view. Any one can help me out to display multiple images in collection view. Below is my code.

```
if (reveiewSenderInfoCaseDetail){
    NSLog(@"My review Info");
    UIView *eigthView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2290, 150,550)];
    eigthView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:eigthView];
    UILabel *beforeParcelLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 180, 50)];
    beforeParcelLabel.text = @"Before Parcel:";
    beforeParcelLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    beforeParcelLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
    [eigthView addSubview:beforeParcelLabel];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    beforeParcelCollectionViews = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [beforeParcelCollectionViews setFrame:CGRectMake(5,35,100,500)];//(20,35,500,90)];//(5,45,90,500)];//(5, 45, 500, 90)];
    [beforeParcelCollectionViews setDataSource:self];
    [beforeParcelCollectionViews setDelegate:self];
    [beforeParcelCollectionViews setTag:600];
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(320, 548)];
    //collectionView.layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    [beforeParcelCollectionViews registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [beforeParcelCollectionViews setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];//[UIColor redColor]];
    [eigthView addSubview:beforeParcelCollectionViews];
    UIView *ninthView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 2290, 310,550)];
    ninthView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:ninthView];
    UILabel *aftrParcelLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 180, 50)];
    aftrParcelLabel.text = @"After Parcel:";
    aftrParcelLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:226.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    aftrParcelLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
    [ninthView addSubview:aftrParcelLabel];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout2=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    layout2.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    afterParcelCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [afterParcelCollectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(5,35,100,500)];//(5,45,90,500)];//(5, 45, 500, 90)];
    [afterParcelCollectionView setDataSource:self];
    [afterParcelCollectionView setDelegate:self];
    [afterParcelCollectionView setTag:601];
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(320, 548)];
    [afterParcelCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [afterParcelCollectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];//[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [ninthView addSubview:afterParcelCollectionView];
    }
    // -loadView
    [self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    // -dealloc
    [self.view removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
 }
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [afterParcelCollectionView reloadData];
    [beforeParcelCollectionViews reloadData];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (collectionView.tag == 600)
    {
        return imageArray.count;
    }
    else 
    return imageArray2.count;
 }

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell;
    if (collectionView.tag == 601)
    {
        cell = [afterParcelCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIImageView *myImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 80)];
        myImageView2.tag = 102;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView2];

        NSString *myImage= [imageArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self imageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]] callback:^(UIImage *image1){
            myImageView2.image =image1;
        }];
    }
    if (collectionView.tag == 600)
    {
        cell = [beforeParcelCollectionViews dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 80)];
        myImageView.tag = 101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];

        NSString *myImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]] callback:^(UIImage *image){
            myImageView.image =image;
        }];
    }
    return cell;

}


-(void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL *) url callback:(void(^)(UIImage *image))callback
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            callback(image);
        });
    });
}

-(void)imageFromURL:(NSURL *) url callback:(void(^)(UIImage *image1))callback
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            callback(image1);
        });
    });
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (reveiewSenderInfoCaseDetail)
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 400, 0,400);
      }

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0,400);
}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return CGSizeMake(100,80);
}
```

Comment: did you check the count of `imageArray.count` and `imageArray2.count` ??

Comment: Not able to get the count

Comment: What do you mean by that ?? Just check the count in `numberOfItemsInSection`, put NSLog there to get the count.

Comment: NSLog(@"MY Count of Image Array %lu",(unsigned long)imageArray.count);...... this shows an error code will never excite i do that

Comment: Put that above return statement.

Comment: Yes now i able to get the count of image

Comment: And what are you getting in that count, will you tell us ??

Comment: You are getting  MY Count of Image Array2 of imageArray2.count 0, ie the count of imageArray2.count is 0, so how will you show this images in second CollectView ???

Comment: Really not able to get you, edit your question and describe your problem very clearly.Thats my suggestion.

Comment: I am showing u the result of image array.count .. @rajatp

Comment: Also create your views on stroyboard. it will be a good design pattern.

Comment: Which collection view are you not able to see, first one or second one ??

Comment: in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` add breakpoint at `cell = [beforeParcelCollectionViews dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89342/discussion-between-nisha-gupta-and-rajatp).